# "Warning: Potentially polymorphic call" when calling a method on a entity repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm

My Entity `Item` has a Repository (`ItemRepository`) with the function `findItemCount()`. When I use

```
$repository = $em->getRepository(Item::class);    
$items = $repository->findItemCount();
```

I get the warning:

> Potentially polymorphic call. The code may be inoperable depending on the actual class instance passed as the argument.

Also the auto completion doesn't suggest me the function "findItemCount". What is my mistake?

Controller:

```
/**
 * Artikel Liste
 * @Route("/item/list", name="app_item_list")
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 * @return Response
 */
public function listItems(EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $repository = $em->getRepository(Item::class);
    $items = $repository->findItemCount();

    return $this->render('item_admin/itemList.html.twig', [
        'items' => $items,
        'title' => 'Artikel Übersicht',
        'blocked' => false
    ]);
}
```

Item.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OrderBy;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Itemparent", inversedBy="item")
     */
    private $itemparent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Itemgroup", inversedBy="items")
     */
    private $itemgroup;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $minsize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $charge;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $blocked;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Barcode", mappedBy="item", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $barcodes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ItemStock", mappedBy="item", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $itemStocks;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\BookingItem", mappedBy="item", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bookingItems;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SupplierItems::class, mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $supplierItems;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ItemStockCharge::class, mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $itemStockCharges;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->barcodes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->itemStocks = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->suppliers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->supplierItems = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->itemStockCharges = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getItemparent(): ?Itemparent
    {
        return $this->itemparent;
    }

    public function setItemparent(?Itemparent $itemparent): self
    {
        $this->itemparent = $itemparent;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getItemgroup(): ?Itemgroup
    {
        return $this->itemgroup;
    }

    public function setItemgroup(?Itemgroup $itemgroup): self
    {
        $this->itemgroup = $itemgroup;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMinsize(): ?string
    {
        return $this->minsize;
    }

    public function setMinsize(string $minsize): self
    {
        $this->minsize = $minsize;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCharge(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->charge;
    }

    public function setCharge(bool $charge): self
    {
        $this->charge = $charge;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBlocked(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->blocked;
    }

    public function setBlocked(bool $blocked): self
    {
        $this->blocked = $blocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Barcode[]
     */
    public function getBarcodes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->barcodes;
    }

    public function addBarcode(Barcode $barcode): self
    {
        if (!$this->barcodes->contains($barcode)) {
            $this->barcodes[] = $barcode;
            $barcode->setItem($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBarcode(Barcode $barcode): self
    {
        if ($this->barcodes->contains($barcode)) {
            $this->barcodes->removeElement($barcode);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($barcode->getItem() === $this) {
                $barcode->setItem(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ItemStock[]
     */
    public function getItemStocks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->itemStocks;
    }

    public function addItemStock(ItemStock $itemStock): self
    {
        if (!$this->itemStocks->contains($itemStock)) {
            $this->itemStocks[] = $itemStock;
            $itemStock->setItem($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItemStock(ItemStock $itemStock): self
    {
        if ($this->itemStocks->contains($itemStock)) {
            $this->itemStocks->removeElement($itemStock);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($itemStock->getItem() === $this) {
                $itemStock->setItem(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|BookingItem[]
     */
    public function getBookingItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookingItems;
    }

    public function addBookingItem(BookingItem $bookingItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->bookingItems->contains($bookingItem)) {
            $this->bookingItems[] = $bookingItem;
            $bookingItem->setItem($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBookingItem(BookingItem $bookingItem): self
    {
        if ($this->bookingItems->contains($bookingItem)) {
            $this->bookingItems->removeElement($bookingItem);
            if ($bookingItem->getItem() === $this) {
                $bookingItem->setItem(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(?float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCommaPrice(): string
    {
        return number_format($this->price, 2, ',', '');
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|SupplierItems[]
     */
    public function getSupplierItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->supplierItems;
    }

    public function addSupplierItem(SupplierItems $supplierItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->supplierItems->contains($supplierItem)) {
            $this->supplierItems[] = $supplierItem;
            $supplierItem->setItem($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSupplierItem(SupplierItems $supplierItem): self
    {
        if ($this->supplierItems->contains($supplierItem)) {
            $this->supplierItems->removeElement($supplierItem);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($supplierItem->getItem() === $this) {
                $supplierItem->setItem(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ItemStockCharge[]
     */
    public function getItemStockCharges(): Collection
    {
        return $this->itemStockCharges;
    }

    public function addItemStockCharge(ItemStockCharge $itemStockCharge): self
    {
        if (!$this->itemStockCharges->contains($itemStockCharge)) {
            $this->itemStockCharges[] = $itemStockCharge;
            $itemStockCharge->setItem($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItemStockCharge(ItemStockCharge $itemStockCharge): self
    {
        if ($this->itemStockCharges->contains($itemStockCharge)) {
            $this->itemStockCharges->removeElement($itemStockCharge);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($itemStockCharge->getItem() === $this) {
                $itemStockCharge->setItem(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

ItemRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Item;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Item|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Item|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Item[]    findAll()
 * @method Item[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class ItemRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Item::class);
    }

    public function findItem()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.blocked = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', false)
            ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }

    public function findBlockedItemCount()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('item')
            ->select('item, SUM(stocks.count) as sums')
            ->andWhere('item.blocked = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', true)
            ->leftJoin('item.itemStocks', 'stocks')
            ->groupBy('item')
            ->orderBy('item.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }

    public function findItemCount(){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('item')
            ->select('item, SUM(stocks.count) as sums')
            ->andWhere('item.blocked = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', false)
            ->leftJoin('item.itemStocks', 'stocks')
            ->groupBy('item')
            ->orderBy('item.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IDE has no way of knowing that `$em->getRepository(Item::class);` will return `ItemRepository`, since the type of the returned object not resolved until runtime.

Inject `ItemRepository` instead of the entity manager, it's the better practice in any case:

```
public function listItems(ItemRepository $itemRepository): Response
{
    $items = $itemRepository->findItemCount();
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hint your IDE about the variable type

```
/** @var ItemRepository $repository */
$repository = $em->getRepository(Item::class);    
$items = $repository->findItemCount();
```